# Дієслово від "хам", "хамство"?

Tags: вживання-слів, дієслова, росіянізм

СУМ містить іменники [**`хамство`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/khamstvo) і [**`хам`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/kham), але не містить відповідного дієслова [**`хамити`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/khamyty), як і [результати пошуку у Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&title=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA&go=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8&searchToken=43zi079xnaz8vvqfdzlhzt8p4) не показують такої статті.

Водночас, ресурс [Всесвітній словник української мови](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) наводить не тільки усі форми дієслова **`хамити`**, а й форми дієприслівника.

[Google пошук](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8+%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E&oq=%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j35i39j0l4.2733j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&start=10) також свідчить на користь існування такого дієслова.

**Тож чи зафіксоване дієслово `хамити` в якихось інших словниках української мови? Якщо ні, то який йому український відповідник?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, [орфографічний словник від Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) таке слово **[містить](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8)**. А Український мовно-інформаційний фонд є науково-дослідним інститутом Національної академії наук України — тож вважатимемо, що таке слово **існує**.

Знаходжу трапляння цього слова і в [корпусі](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx), щоправда поодинокі та лише в сучасних авторів: Лариса Денисенко, Любко Дереш, Роман Іваничук, інші.

Найстаріше використання, що я знайшов (не факт, що справді найстаріше): [«Розбиваю громи» Олеся Бердника (1967)](//books.google.com/books?id=bGLqAAAAMAAJ&q=%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8).

Answer (score 6):

В інших словниках

> <sup>[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&highlight=on) [[показник]](https://r2u.org.ua/html/announcement.html)</sup>
> **Хамить, нахамить** – хамити, поводитися (повестися) по-хамському (хамовито, як хам).

---

Деякі відповідники можна вже одразу брати  з опису СУМ

- грубість ⇒ [грубіянити](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghrubijanyty)
- нахабство ⇒ [нахабничати](http://sum.in.ua/s/nakhabnychaty), [нахабніти](http://sum.in.ua/s/nakhabnity)